# how to customise search results of apachesolr (drupal 6)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, solr

can somebody help me how to customize the search result of a apache solr search. i was only able to access these variables **[comment_count] => [created] => [id] => [name] => [nid] => [title] => [type] => [uid] => [url] => [score] => [body]**.

how can i access other variable like **status, vote ....** from the index ( i don't want to access the database for retrieving these values, i want to get it from the index itself)

i need to display no of votes for that specific node in the result snippet

i need to understand
 1. how to index votes field 
 2. how to show the **vote, status**... in result snippet.

Comment: the short answer is you have to request all the fields you need through, by default only these fields will be sent in response 
d,nid,title,comment_count,type,created,changed,score,path,url,uid,name

function formexample_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params) {
  $params['fl'] .= ',field_desc';
  $params['fl'] .= ',field_url';
}

Answer (score 2):

Votes are a poor choice for indexing for a couple of reasons:

- Votes can change quickly
- When a vote is made, the node is not updated. As such, apachesolr won't know to re-index the node to pick up the change.

If by 'status' you mean the node->status value, then the answer is that it will always be 1.  Unpublished nodes are never indexed.

Now, if you want to add something *else* to the index, you want `hook_apachesolr_update_index(&$document, $node)` - this hook gets called as each node is being indexed, and you can add fields to $document from $node to get the values into the solr index.  However, you want to use the pre-defined field prefixes - look at schema.xml to find the list.

Comment: +1 for mentioning pre-defined field prefixes - that just answered my problem.

Comment: Great answer but you miss the part of being able to retrieve the values in the search results too.

Answer (score 2):

Below is example of code to add fields for sorting, and for output.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_apachesolr_update_index()
 * Here we're adding custom fields to index, so that they available for sorting. To make this work, it's required to re-index content.
 */
function somemodule_apachesolr_update_index(&$document, $node) {
  if ($node->type == 'product') {
    $document->addField('sm_default_qty', $node->default_qty);
    $document->addField('sm_sell_price', $node->sell_price);
    $document->addField('sm_model', $node->model);
    foreach ($node->field_images AS $image) {
      //$imagecached_filepath = imagecache_create_path('product', $image['filepath']);
      $document->addField('sm_field_images', $image['filepath']);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_apachesolr_modify_query()
 * Here we point what additional fields we need to get from solr
 */
function somemodule_apachesolr_modify_query(&$query, &$params, $caller) {
  $params['fl'] .= ',sm_default_qty,sm_field_images,sm_sell_price,sm_model';
}
```

If you want to totally customize output, you should do following:
1) Copy search-results.tpl.php and search-result.tpl.php from /modules/search to your theme's folder.
2) Use the $result object as needed within search-result.tpl.php
3) Don't forget to clear the theme registry by visiting admin/build/themes

Or as mentioned about, you can override using preprocessor hooks.

Regards, Slava

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a view(s) of your liking with input argument nid, then create the following preprocess in your template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$vars) {

$vars['myView'] = views_embed_view('myView', 'default', $vars['result']['node']->nid);

}
```

Matching the view name 'myView' with the variable name makes sense to me.  Then you can use the variable $myView in your search-results.tpl.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video by the makers of the Solr Search Integration module with an overview on how to customise what nodes and fields are indexed, and what Solr spits out as a search result...

For Drupal 6:
http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/apache-solr-search-mastery.html

And Drupal 7:
http://www.acquia.com/resources/acquia-tv/conference/apache-solr-search-mastery

It all looks very customisable!